# Cordova 3.3 "device" Plugin not working on an iOS build

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova

Installed the plugin using the direction. None of the `device` properties work in the index.js. When used they all hang up the device.

installed cordova.

did a build for ios then

`phonegap local plugin add https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-device.git`

the in the index.js after `deviceready` have an alert for `device.name` or `device.uuid` or any-other device property will not work

Comment: Can you share the code which you tried?

Comment: yes all I had was `alert(device.name` or `device.uuid` it hangs up the app there and I need to use those properties.

Comment: You need to add the plugin first, then do the build.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi "git" is also a node module. you should install plugin like this.

npm install -g git

This will install git in you node source location as a module.

Restart the machine.

Install phonegap plugin:
C:\Users\user1\yourprojectname>cordova plugin add https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-camera.git

You will get response as:
Fetching plugin from "https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-cam
era.git"...
Starting installation of "org.apache.cordova.camera" for android
Preparing android project
org.apache.cordova.camera installed on android.

Hope this will be very helpful. If any issue reply.